# Flutter dart replace replace Json object with variables

Tags: flutter, dart

In this case I have class. Where I took a variable. Also I have a Json map. So I want to change Json map object replace with variables. Here is my code example....

So how can I achieve that

I want replace Json object with dart variable

```
class Data {
  late String slug;
  Map<String, String> singleProductVariable = {"slug": "$slug"};
}
```

Comment: There's no JSON in your example, just Dart.  Where's your JSON, and how does it impact this dart code?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there is no JSON in your code sample.

I assume that you would like to set the value of the corresponding key in your Map when setting the variable.
If so, you might want to use a setter in a next way:

```dart
class Data {
  String _slug;
  late Map<String, String> v = {"slug": _slug};

  Data(String slug) : _slug = slug;

  set slug(String str) => v['slug'] = str;
}

void main() {
  final d = Data("slug");
  print(d.v);

  d.slug = "newSlug";
  print(d.v);
}
```

The output of the code above will be:

```
{slug: val}
{slug: newVal}
```